# MPI_Recv takes a long and strange time to return

Tags: openmpi

I am trying to compare the execution time of two programs:
-the first one uses non blocking functions MPI_Ssend and MPI_Irecv, which allows to do some calculations "while messages are being sent and received".
-the other one uses blocking OpenMPI functions.

I have no problem to assess the performances of the first program and they look "good".
My problem is that the second program, that uses MPI_Recv, often takes a very long and kind of "strange" time to finish : always a little bit more than 1 second : (for example 1.001033 seconds). As if the process had to do something that takes exactly 1 second.
I modified my initial code to show you an equivalent one.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 5000

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    MPI_Request trash;

    int rank;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int myVector[SIZE];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < SIZE ; i++)
        myVector[i] = 100;

    int buff[SIZE];

    double startTime = MPI_Wtime();

    if(rank == 0)
      MPI_Issend(myVector, SIZE, MPI_INT, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &trash);
    if(rank == 1) {
      MPI_Recv(buff, SIZE, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, NULL);
      printf("Processus 1 finished in %lf seconds\n", MPI_Wtime()-startTime);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You must wait on the Isend before calling Finalize. Use blocking Send instead for this example.

Comment: @Jeff Thank you this was the cause of the problem.